# Why is $L^\infty$ a "good" choice for solutions of many PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, intuition, parabolic-pde

I have a very naive question.
Why is the function space $L^{\infty}$ so "good" and often used as the solution space for PDE?

I guess the reason is that it is some kind of "natural candidate" in order to get solutions that do not blow-up.

Comment: It is not. For instance, the lack of reflexivity alone leads to several problems. It also does not contain any information about derivatives.In many situations, $W^{1,2}$ is a far more natural choice. I surely misundestand your question, but when and how is $L^\infty$ used as a solution space?

Comment: Often one can use the fact that a solution is bounded to derive even more regularity for your solution. It might be useful if you mention some examples where $L^\infty$ is used as a solution space.